# Using \COPY to load CSV with JSON fields into Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, csv, psql, postgresql-9.4

I'm attempting to load TSV data from a file into a Postgres table using the \COPY command.

Here's an example data row:

```
2017-11-22 23:00:00     "{\"id\":123,\"class\":101,\"level\":3}"
```

Here's the psql command I'm using:

```
\COPY bogus.test_table (timestamp, sample_json) FROM '/local/file.txt' DELIMITER E'\t'
```

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "sample_json" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: "{"sample_json...
COPY test_table, line 1, column sample_json: ""{\"id\":123,\"class\":101,\"level\":3}""
```

I verified the JSON is in the correct JSON format and read a couple similar questions, but I'm still not sure what's going on here. An explanation would be awesome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To load your data file as it is:

```
\COPY bogus.test_table (timestamp, sample_json) FROM '/local/file.txt' CSV DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: Works perfectly in psql and adapated it to work in a python script, thanks dude!

Comment: did the trick for me too also for very complicated and nested and crazy in terms of content JSON fields.

Comment: @lemonmaster could you share a gist of the python script?

Comment: @moshevi unfortunately I can't do that since it's related to work (the script has since been changed). If you're using psycopg2 you can use cursor.copy_from(), which is what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Aeblisto almost did the trick for my crazy JSON fields, but needed to modify an only small bit - **THE QUOTE with backslash** - here it is in full form:

```
COPY "your_schema_name.yor_table_name" (your, column_names, here) 
FROM STDIN 
WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE E'\b' ESCAPE '\';
--here rows data
\.
```

Comment: I have a different but related problem: I want to export JSONB data as json text.  I tried the above command but using "\copy" instead, and in output format, like `\copy (select my_column from my_table where id='some_id') TO 'my_output.txt' WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE '\b' ESCAPE '\';` which produced the error "quote must be a single one-byte character".  Changing from `QUOTE '\b'` to `QUOTE E'\b'` fixed this and i get valid JSON output.  I would imagine the same change works for the input if anyone has the the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is quoted. It shouldn't have surrounding `"` characters, and the `"` characters surrounding the field names shouldn't be escaped.

It should look like this:

```
2017-11-22 23:00:00 {"id":123,"class":101,"level":3}
```