# PostgresSQL COPY Data From CSV File Contain Data Type JSON/JSONB

Tags: postgresql, copy

I have the data type of the table as follows

```
column1: varchar(255)
column2: text
column3: json
column4: jsonb
column5: integer
```

I use fputcsv() of PHP to create file from array.

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5
"Data coulm 1","Data coulm 2",[], "[{""column4"":123}]",1
```

I used the following sql to copy

```
COPY table FROM 'path/to/file.csv'
   CSV HEADER  DELIMITER ',';
```

but I cannot import it,

How to import a CSV file that table contains json/jsonb data type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using \COPY to load CSV with JSON fields into Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340041/using-copy-to-load-csv-with-json-fields-into-postgres)

Comment: in Laravel i'm using \COPY then I get the following error ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"

Comment: "but I cannot import it" is not a good description of a problem.